# Android - How to check which nfc mode is enabled?

Tags: android

NfcAdapter.isEnabled() returns false when nfc is off and card emulation mode.

1. How to check which nfc mode is enabled?
2. How to distinguish between card emulation mode and off state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked which nfc mode was turned on with BroadcastReceiver.
When the nfc card emulation mode is on, I can get null or 5 as state on the receiver.

```
val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        val action = intent.action
        if (action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED) {
            val state = intent.getIntExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ADAPTER_STATE,NfcAdapter.STATE_OFF)
                    
            when (state) {
                NfcAdapter.STATE_OFF -> { /* nfc off */ }
                NfcAdapter.STATE_ON -> { /* nfc Rader/Witer Mode */ }
                else -> { /* nfc Card Emulation Mode */}
            }
        }
    }
}

context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED))
```